# Modified vendor files, Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm currently using Laravel 7.xx, and during working on my project, I change some vendor files, modify it

Because few things doesn't work for me, so without any option left, I have to modify some vendor files.

In case if I ever want / need to update my laravel / packages version, will the modified vendor files revert back to original state and I lost all my modified code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes and you shouldn't be making any changes to those files in the first place !!

Comment: if you think your changes will improve the package you should send a pull request to that package so that you don't have to change it manually. If the package owner doesn't accept your pull request, you may have to fork and maintain that package on your own.

Comment: Probably you don't actually need to change these files. Rethink your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! whenever you do composer install or composer update, your modified vendor files will revert back. So, you never should edit any vendor files.
What you can do is extend those specific classes to new files of your own

1. Make a new file of the class that you are overriding : (e.g : app/Overrides/MyClass.php)
2. in your composer.json

   ```
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "vendor/pathtotheYourVendorFileThatYouAreOverriding.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Illuminate\\": "app/Overrides/"
    }
   ```